# Update values in table many times in minute

Tags: python, psycopg2

I need to call Update many times in minute. Is it the correct way to do this? I think not, cuz sometimes i get Exception - `cursor already closed`. I call this func from many threads, may be need to lock this part?

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='MyDB', user='...', password='...', host='127.0.0.1')
cursor = conn.cursor()

def update_data(name,type, value):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Datas SET Value = %s WHERE Name = %s and Type = %s", (value, name, type))
    conn.commit()
```

Or i need to open connection and initialize cursor everytime ? I'm calling `update_data` about 600 times in minute.

I need to see live data updates on the site. This information may be needed.

Also below I use `with conn.cursor()`, perhaps there is an intersection of two cursor objects and an error occurs. I didn't notice that I was using different options with the cursor, I was in a hurry.

```
def get_all_data():
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute('SELECT * FROM Datas')
        datas = curs.fetchall()
        return datas
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you are showing is closing the cursor, there must be another portion of the code that does that. Add it to the question text.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver In the other part of code i use 2-5 threads with while True: and sometimes they call the function update_data. That's all. I havent large program. But I call this function very often, perhaps the error is triggered because of this.

Comment: You didn't answer my request. I asked for the code that closes the cursor.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the code, didn't think that the new local cursor closes the global one too

Comment: Per [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html): *Cursors can be used as context managers: leaving the context will close the cursor.*. Also: *Cursors created from the same connection are not isolated, i.e., any changes done to the database by a cursor are immediately visible by the other cursors.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some tests with psycopg2, i started creating a connection and a cursor for each request and the errors went away. But I understand that this is not the best implementation

```
def get_all_datas():
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname='DatasDB', user='fr3sto', password='********', host='127.0.0.1') as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as curs:
            curs.execute('SELECT * FROM Datas')
            datas = curs.fetchall()
            return datas
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that, connections are expensive. Either: 1) Open a connection and create cursors off it outside a context manager so they don't close on completion. 2) Use [connection pooling](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the tips, I'll use them

Answer (score 1):

Instead of committing for every data, how about storing the data in a list for some time like make the function commit only when there are 1000 data items. that will make your code efficient. You can use a list to store the data instead of committing. Then only run update when the `len()` of list is more than 1000. pass the list to update() function and run a for loop inside it. Then commit after everything is executed.